# Artin-Mazur codiagonal preserves Kan objects?

Tags: ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff

The Artin-Mazur codiagonal $\nabla:ssSet \to sSet$ is right adjoint to the total decalage functor $Dec:sSet \to ssSet$. The total decalage functor is defined to be precomposition with the ordinal sum functor $+:\Delta\times \Delta \to \Delta$, $+([n],[m]) = [n+m+1]$.

If we agree to call a bisimplicial set $X= ([n]\times [m] \mapsto X_{nm})$ a *bi-Kan complex* if each simplicial set $[k] \mapsto X_{km}$ and $[k] \mapsto X_{nk}$ is a Kan complex (for all $n$ and $m$), then I'm wondering if it is known in the literature whether $\nabla X$ is a Kan complex. Perhaps in Artin-Mazur's monograph?

Note that a bi-Kan complex is not necessarily the same as an internal Kan complex in the category of Kan complexes (I haven't checked this - just a warning)

Comment: For some reason, I think that the only people who can answer this are Tim Porter or Phil Ehlers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Harry is wrong! Antonio CEGARRA,  B. A. HEREDIA, and J. REMEDIOS: see http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1003/1003.3820v1.pdf, page 9. Fact 2.8. give the answer in a recent preprint. They know that stuff much better than I do!

Comment: Let this be the only answer I ever vote up that begins with "Harry is wrong!".

Comment: Not that I have a problem with being wrong, just that I have a healthy respect for irony.